# Pre Loader Not Hide after Page Loaded in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Pre Loader Not Hide after Page Loaded in asp.net. I have tried two javascript code. But not helpfull.

Xaml Code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).load(function () { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
            jQuery("#status").fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
            jQuery("#preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow"); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
        })
</script>

<body >
    <div id="preloader">
          <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

Coding...
```

Xaml Code -

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
            function hide_preloader() {
                $("#preloader").fadeOut(100);
            }
    </script>

    <body onload="hide_preloader();" > 
        <div id="preloader">
              <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
..CODEING...
```

Image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
            jQuery("#status").fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
            jQuery("#preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow"); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
        });
```